# How to change UIbutton title once a UIbutton is pressed?

Tags: ios5, uibutton

I am having trouble changing the title of UIButton btn2 once btn1 is pressed.  When I use `_definition settitle:@"Show Word" forState: UIControlStateNormal` it changes the original btn1.

Here is the code for your review,

```
- (IBAction)mynextPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    //Display the string in the label field

    [self.WordDisplay setText:vocabulary];

    //reset center button with "show word"
    [_definitionPressed setTitle:@"Show Word" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"displaying word: %@", _definitionPressed.titleLabel);

}
```

Comment: Simply check your nib file for wiring of second button's outlet with its property. It looks like your second button's outlet is set with first button's property.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
[btn2 setTitle:@"Show Word"]
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try this way:

```
[_definitionPressed setTitle:@"Normal State" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_definitionPressed setTitle:@"Selected State" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```