# XCode How to change the text of a button when another button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change UIbutton title once a UIbutton is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966769/how-to-change-uibutton-title-once-a-uibutton-is-pressed)

I want to change the text of a UIButton when another UIButton is pressed any idea?

Comment: How about `setTitle:forState:`?

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966769/how-to-change-uibutton-title-once-a-uibutton-is-pressed). This did not take much to find, some people can be a bit weird about not doing much research into your questions so be prepare to get a lot of duplicated questions and people giving you bad rep for it.

Please read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for help on making a good question.